# Declare DAO classes as class members or method arguments for Spring autowire?

Tags: java, spring

I am a beginner to Spring autowire and has seen different type of autowire implementation.

There are 2 common methods as shown below to autowire persistence layer to the service layer.

Which is a better way of autowiring the persistence layer to the service layer?

```
 @Service
 public class SomeServiceImpl {

   @Autowired
   private CustomerDAO customerDAO;


  public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
     return customerDAO.getAllCustomer();   
  }
}
```

vs

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  public List<Customer> getAllCustomer(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
     return customerDAO.getAllCustomer();   
  }
}
```

Comment: I would go with first one as it will make the testing easier.

Comment: private @Autowired is the best method, the DAO will be usefull potentially for the whole service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the above. Although opinionated you shouldn't use field injection (see [this](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) and [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/)).

The second one wouldn't even work unless you would be passing the `CustomerDAO` around yourself.

Instead make the field `final` and use constructor based injection.

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl {

    private final CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
        this.customerDAO= customerDAO;
    }
}
```

Still easy to test, pass the dao to the constructor and no need to pass it around. Nothing is hidden anymore (less magic) and you still honor OO rules (that an object should be in a valid state after construction).

You could even put a validation inside the constructor to check if the passed in argument isn't `null`.

Comment: well said. but afair this does not work on older spring versions (3.x and older).  in this case skip the final but stick with constructor injection.

Comment: It works on any spring version... Might be if you use field i injection but using constructor injection it will just work.

Comment: @M.Deinum how about service class with multiple dao? I should autowire all dao classes via the constructor?

Comment: If they are required yes. If it is a mess, that is probably a sign you have some flaws in your architecture.

Comment: @M.Deinum does it mean that each service class should have 1 dao?

Comment: I'm not going to give an answer on that, that is for a different question on a completely different topic.

Answer (score 1):

In general, The good practice would be to put the @Autowired on a constructor instead of a method. If you put it on a constructor, you can validate that the injected beans are not null and fail fast when you try to start the application and avoid a NullPointerException when you need to actually use the bean.

There are no of advantage with

```
@Autowired
 private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
```

1) You can use it into whole service class.

2) As explained above if it fail then you will notify on start the application